# soft keyboard on Android

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

There are 4 different activities in application. While passing in activities, soft keyboard opens automatically. To fix this I used

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

but this time when I open keyboard for editText, keyboard cast over the layout that I use at the bottom of the activity. Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

Add this code in your `manifestfile.xml`.all `Activity`

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest file add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```

Check the developer [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for more details

Comment: this time all layout slide up when keyboard is open. to fix this I am using
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: try this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`